# foreach with cycle/alternate options

Tags: php, foreach

I am looking for a fastest(performance) way to cycle/alternative 2 values inside of a foreach loop. Exactly the same as the smarty works: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.cycle

Comment: If you have a specific problem with your existing code, we are happy to assist you. Questions that require subjective answers are better answered on programmers.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$cycle = array('value1', 'value2');
$i = 0;

foreach (...) {
    $cycle[$i] // current cycle value
    ...
    $i = 1 - $i; // here be cycling
}
```

P.S. And don't think you should be *very* concerned about performance in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Cycling is easy with the modulo operator.

```
$cycle = $iteration % $cycles;
```

If `$cycles` is **2**, for instance, then `$cycle` will contain **0** and **1** alternating as `$iteration` increases.

Then if you need specific values for these cycles, use a look-up table:

```
$lookup = array('value1', 'value2');
$value = $lookup[$cycle];
```

The `foreach` loop does not keep track of iterations, though; You'd want to use a `for` loop for that instead. Or increment an iteration variable yourself.

Comment: `1 - $i` flip is way cooler ;-) Yours in universal, but question is about exactly 2 values.